# How do I fix build errors when trying to build 64 bit binaries of log4cxx?

Tags: c++, logging, log4cxx

I'm looking to compile and use log4cxx under Windows 7 64 bit, and would like to link it to a 64 bit application (I needed 32 bit binaries too, but I've found copies of those). I've found an "up to date" project that supposedly compiles under windows at "http://www.dreamcubes.com/b2/software-development/28/log4cxx-for-win32-with-vs2005/", but I get a bunch of `an explicit instantiation of a template can only occur at namespace scope` errors when trying to build.

Does anyone happen to know a method of fixing these build issues?

Comment: As the accepted answer is no longer valid, I can add this question as a reference that helped me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8461123/building-log4cxx-in-vs-2010-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [building log4cxx in vs 2010 c++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8461123) (per the accepted answer).